# Unable to parse this field for main time only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a datetime column with data as:

```
2018-01-28 09:45:12.797 -05:00
```

I would like to have this display only the time, the 09:45 part of the time.

I tried such a formula:

```
IF istime(Left(Split({qryPtWaitingTme_.SCHED_TIMEOUT}, ' ')[2],8)) then 
Time(Left(Split({qryPtWaitingTme_.SCHED_TIMEOUT}, ' ')[2],8))
```

but it fails, with this error:

'A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of many solutions might be:

```
select convert(varchar(5),cast(qryPtWaitingTme_.SCHED_TIMEOUT as time), 120)
```